# Qsort not sorting struct elements correctly

Tags: c, sorting, struct, io, qsort

I'm writing some code that reads in a binary file, sorts it, then writes it out to and output file sorted in lexicographical order. I'm not throwing any errors with any of it except for the sorting of the various elements.

```
struct lab1_data
{
    float goodbye;
    char balance;
    unsigned char clouds;
    float badge;
    double soda;
    char bat;
    short int parcel;
    char vessel;
    char spade;
    long int cover;
    unsigned long int hobbies;
    short int voyage;
    int stomach;
    char sort;
    char system [11];
    unsigned short  adjustment;
};


int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    struct lab1_data** a1 = (struct lab1_data**) a;
    struct lab1_data** b1 = (struct lab1_data**) b;

    if ((*a1)->soda > (*b1)->soda)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if ((*b1)->soda < (*b1)->soda)
    {
        return -1;

    }

    if ((*a1)->stomach > (*b1)->stomach)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((*b1)->stomach < (*b1)->stomach)
    {
        return 1;

    }
    if ((*a1)->bat > (*b1)->bat)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((*b1)->bat < (*b1)->bat)
    {
        return 1;

    }
    //This keeps going for all elements, just varying descending/ascending order.
    .
    .
    .
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int size = 8;
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    struct lab1_data *lab1_struct;
    lab1_struct = (struct lab1_data*) malloc (size * sizeof(struct lab1_data));

    if (!lab1_struct)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory");
        exit(-2) ;
    }

    FILE *fh_i = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    FILE *fh_o = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect file names");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!fh_o)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s.", argv[2]);
        exit(-3);
    }
    if (!fh_i)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s.", argv[1]);
        exit(-3);
    }

    while (!feof(fh_i))
    {
        if (count == size)
        {
            size = size * 2;
            lab1_struct = realloc(lab1_struct, sizeof(struct lab1_data) * size);
        }

        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].goodbye, sizeof(float), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].balance, sizeof(char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].clouds, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].badge, sizeof(float), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].soda, sizeof(double), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].bat, sizeof(char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].parcel, sizeof(short), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].vessel, sizeof(char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].spade, sizeof(char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].cover, sizeof(long), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].hobbies, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].voyage, sizeof(short), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].stomach, sizeof(int), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].sort, sizeof(char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].system, 11 * sizeof(char), 1, fh_i);
        fread((void*)&lab1_struct[count].adjustment, sizeof(short), 1, fh_i);

        count++;
    }

    struct lab1_data** plab1_struct = (struct lab1_data**) malloc (size * 8);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        plab1_struct[i] = &lab1_struct[i];
    }

    qsort(plab1_struct, count - 1, 8, compare);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).goodbye, sizeof(float), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).balance, sizeof(char), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).clouds, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).badge, sizeof(float), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).soda, sizeof(double), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).bat, sizeof(char), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).vessel, sizeof(short), 1 , fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).parcel, sizeof(char), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).spade, sizeof(char), 1 , fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).cover, sizeof(long), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).hobbies, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).voyage, sizeof(short), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).stomach, sizeof(int), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).sort, sizeof(char), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).system, 11 * sizeof(char), 1, fh_o);
        fwrite((void*) & (*plab1_struct[i]).adjustment, sizeof(short), 1, fh_o);
    }

    fclose(fh_i);
    fclose(fh_o);

    free(lab1_struct);
    free(plab1_struct);

    return 0;
}
```

None of my elements are getting sorted at all. I was sure that I had the qsort functions called and initialised properly, I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: You should do some debugging, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Checking `argc` *after* using `argv` isn't a good idea.

Comment: Why did you cast to `void *` is this a c++ compiler? Also, `fread(&lab1_struct[count], sizeof(lab1_struct[count]), 1, fh_i);` is shorter don't you think? You just need to ensure the `struct` is packed, i.e. no padding.

Comment: How are the structures saved? Member by member as you read it, or the whole structure at once? Or the whole array of structures at once?

Comment: @MikeCAT From the `fread((void *) ...` I would guess that the OP is using a [tag:c++] compiler.

Comment: `!feof(fh_i)` is [a bad loop condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg See `fwrite()`s ...

Comment: Also, `&(*plab1_struct[i]).` --> `&plab1_struct[i]->`?

Comment: @iharob That only says how the OP is writing the data the OP just read, not how the data was written into the original file that the OP is reading from.

Comment: Using a magic number `8` in `malloc (size * 8)` isn't a good idea. You should use `malloc (size * sizeof(struct lab1_data*))` instead. Using the magic number for the argument of `qsort` is also bad.

Comment: I know, but it's plausible that the OP is using the same kind of loop to save the original data.

Comment: Why are you sorting `count -1` elements instead of `count` elements? -- Ah, maybe due to the bad loop condition.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second array you allocate, the one with pointers to the elements in the first array?

Comment: As for your problem, are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit system? Why aren't you using the `sizeof` operator to get the correct size for the third arguments? This will very much impact the behavior of your code.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes but OP then goes on to use `count` in the next loop.

Comment: I don't understand  why you have over-egged the pudding by making an array of `struct` pointers and sorting *them* instead of just sorting the structs themselves. Get that right first, and if it's too slow, then advance. BTW don't forget to `return 0;` at the end of the `cmp` function.

Comment: Finally, ***learn how to use a debugger!*** Even if you only want to become a hobby programmer, doing it for fun, knowing how to use a debugger and how to step through code line by line, break at certain lines, monitor variable values, knowing all those things are crucial.

Comment: BTW you only need to allocate `count` elements in the pointer array, not `size` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compare function has this line which seems to be a typo as `b1` is used twice:

```
    if ((*b1)->soda < (*b1)->soda)
          ^^            ^^
```

Same applies to:

```
    if ((*b1)->stomach < (*b1)->stomach)

    if ((*b1)->bat < (*b1)->bat)
```

Comment: Good catch, there are several of those tests using the typo-ed pointer name.